# Run python script from django

Tags: python, django

I added some python file in my django project but that python file did not execute. How can i run that python scrip in django.

Comment: What do you mean by "did not execute"? Also you mean using it e.g. in a Django view, or do you mean run a script independently while having access to the Django environment like the database?

Comment: @bakkal i want to run indivisually on background...i want to process some data on backgroung and update.....but in django project.....means when i start django server i want that script to start.......

Answer (score 1):

OK it seems you want to run a script outside of the HTTP request/response cycle,
I'd recommend you make a Django admin command, because a script will need to e.g. have access to the database environment to update records

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from yourapp.models import Thing
import your_script

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Closes the specified poll for voting'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # Do your processing here
        your_script.process(Thing.objects.all())
```

With this you can call `./manage.py process_thing` and it'll run independently

More on Django admin commands here, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/

If the processing is triggered programmatically e.g. from user requests,
you'll have to setup a queue and have a task job created for each request, I'd try Celery, more on that here http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Comment: actually i am trying to load json fixture through python script and this json file i am getting through server.....so here i am continuously listening to server and if any update in json data i am updating through fixtures...for this purpose in need to run script which do all this task....and i want to do this in django project....